# problem in my code> send player when it is enters in area2d 1 to new position or to another area

Tags: godot, gdscript

`hello there
first when i write my code that i want it to send the player from area 1 to area 2 or to another position
it is dose not work i get many problem sometimes the said the

```
``
` E 0:00:17.512   get_node: (Node not found: "Player" (relative to "/root/Root/Area2D").)
  <C++ Error>   Method failed. Returning: nullptr
  <C++ Source>  scene/main/node.cpp:1465 @ get_node()
  <Stack Trace> Area2D.gd:7 @ _on_Area2D_body_entered()
or errors like that that saying the player is not relative or not found 
my code is like this

extends Node2D

var new_position = Vector2(-238, -379)

func _on_Area2D_body_entered(body):
    if body.name == "Player":
        $Player.set_position(`new_position`)`
``
```

so if there another way to send player from area 1 to area 2 or from position to another one please tell me
and with all my thank full for any helps i get `

Answer (score 0):

Is the player a child of the area? No it isn't. Thus the following does not work: `$Player`.

You are being given the object that entered the area, it is `body`. Freaking use it.

```
func _on_Area2D_body_entered(body):
    if body.name == "Player":
        body.position = new_position
```